# NavigationListItem & Sort

Tags: sapui5

I tried to sort a NavigationListItem on a field which is different from the keyfield within the onInit method of the view controller w/o any success.

Note, there is no orderby implementation on the server side.

My xml view which doesn't implement any sorter since orderby isn't implemented: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.tnt.NavigationListItem

```
 <tnt:NavigationList id="navigationList">
    <tnt:NavigationListItem icon="sap-icon://" 
                            expanded="{expanded}" 
                            key="{MY_KEY}" 
                            items="{/MY_PATH}">                                                                                                                         
       <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{MY_CONTENT}" key="{MY_KEY}"></tnt:NavigationListItem>
    </tnt:NavigationListItem>
  </tnt:NavigationList>
```

Here is an attempt to add a sorter that presently doesn't work. First, because return items correspond to the first level of NavigationListItem and secondly probably because of a wrong approach.

```
        var oNavigationList = this.getView().byId('navigationList');
        var aSorter = [];
        aSorter[0] = new sap.ui.model.Sorter('MY_FIELD', true);
        var oItems = oNavigationList.getItems();
        oItems.sort("items", {path: "/MY_PATH", sorter: aSorter});
```

Could you please advice on the appropriate approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your List is bound to ODATA Model, all the sorting will happen at server side. Every time you say, sort, a new request is sent to server. Now, as you said, the server is not supporting `orderby`, I suggest the following approach :

1. Do oDataModel.read and store the data in a JSON Model. [oData Read API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read)
2. Apply the sorting in XML using below code:

   ```
       <tnt:NavigationList id="navigationList">
           <tnt:NavigationListItem icon="sap-icon://"
               expanded="{expanded}" key="{MY_KEY}"
               items="{
                           path : '/MY_PATH',
                           sorter: {
                               path: 'MY_CONTENT',
                               descending: false,
                               group: false
                           },
                       }">
               <tnt:NavigationListItem text="{MY_CONTENT}"
                   key="{MY_KEY}"></tnt:NavigationListItem>
           </tnt:NavigationListItem>
       </tnt:NavigationList>
   ```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Great! I have implemented your recommendation and I could finally sort data. The JSON Model is the one I would like to display but it does not ; data disappear. Could I refer to the oData Model in the XMLView on one side as documented above and replace it on the controller within the onBeforeRendering method with NavigationListItem.setModel method?

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not sure what you mean . Can you help me with some screen shots ?

Comment: Rahul, I could finally make it running thanks to your advices. Here, a codepen with a simplified solution (https://codepen.io/Coopyrightdmin/pen/XzLPvZ?editors=1111)